# How to iterate the HTML elements with some specific condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2

**Problem statement :** `v-for` loop is iterating and binding the data properly in HTML template but not able to iterate it partially based on some condition. Please find below the JSFiddle link for demo.

**Requirement :** In above demo link, for "Second Section" I want to display the input textbox only once which will be vertically aligned center (in front of beta) instead of repeating it multiple times. other values will be repeat (i.e. alpha, beta, gama).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9shktLpj/)

```js
var arr = [{
    sectionName: 'First Section',
  data: ['alpha', 'beta']
}, {
    sectionName: 'Second Section',
  data: ['alpha', 'beta', 'gama']
}];

var myitem = new Vue({
  el: '#my-items',
  data: {
    items: arr
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>

<div id="my-items">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.sectionName }} <hr>
    <div v-for="sectionData in item.data" style="margin: 5px">
      <span style="width:50px;text-align:left;display:inline-block;">{{ sectionData }}</span> <input type="textbox"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Can you post the expected output in HTML form? It's a bit unclear

Comment: @adiga I updated the OP with the expected output screenshot

Comment: @Shamsail I updated the OP with expected output screenshot. Please have a look

Comment: @RohitJindal from where the dynamic value is coming? or being changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass index into your v-for, then use it in conditionals inside the loop. I've modified your example to show the principle. The text box appears for every section on the first loop, or if sectionData === beta. You can see this condition in the v-if.

This works, but in general, every time you use v-for, you should create a component. The structure quickly gets difficult to understand otherwise.

```js
var arr = [{
    sectionName: 'First Section',
  data: ['alpha', 'beta']
}, {
    sectionName: 'Second Section',
  data: ['alpha', 'beta', 'gama']
}];

var myitem = new Vue({
  el: '#my-items',
  data: {
    items: arr
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>

<div id="my-items">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{ item.sectionName }} <hr>
    <div v-for="sectionData in item.data" style="margin: 5px">
      <span style="width:50px;text-align:left;display:inline-block;">{{ sectionData }}</span>
      <input 
        v-if="index === 0 || sectionData === 'beta'"
        type="textbox"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in second section I want to show only one textbox. I added the expected output screenshot in the OP. Can you please have a look.

Comment: We can not put the check `sectionData === 'beta'"` as values are coming dynamically and also its not about `beta`. In second section only one text box should come with vertical aligned.